# SQL Server 2008 pulling in timestamps from postgres

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, postgresql, etl

I'm brand new to sql server, and this is my first etl job. I'm trying to do something that seems relatively simple, but I've been stuck for a few days on it.

At first I was just having issues pulling in timestamps at all from our main postgres database, now I'm pulling them in as converted text strings and using a data conversion step to transform them into a date. If there is a better way to do this I'd be much obliged to be put in the right direction.

the main problem I'm having right now is I have a query of the following form :

```
                                    SELECT
                                        my_table.id,
                                        max(CASE WHEN to_id = 4 THEN stamp
                                                ELSE NULL END) AS date_pending,
                                        min(CASE WHEN to_id = 4 THEN stamp
                                                ELSE NULL END) AS first_date_pending,
                                        max(CASE WHEN to_id = 5 THEN stamp
                                                ELSE NULL END) AS date_sent,
                                        max(CASE WHEN to_id = 11 THEN stamp
                                                ELSE NULL END) AS date_accepted
                                    FROM my_table
                                    WHERE to_id IN (4, 5, 11)
                                    GROUP BY id
```

**full disclosure: the above query is in a subquery which may or may not matter to a driver from what I have read.

the issue I'm having is my data conversion step cannot convert these stamps (even when cast to strings) to dates. I get the following error:

```
Conversion from "DT_I8" to "DT_DBTIMESTAMP2" is not supported.
```

it seems max'ing and min'ing a date changes their reported type...

I can't seem to cast the fields in the query as sql server fails to run the query do to the unknown type DATE.

I'm at a bit of a loss and don't really know what I should be doing at this point.

Comment: I have even tried making functions to convert the stamps, and sql server barks at the query step saying:

the OLE DB adapter cannot convert between types "DT_DBDATE" and "DT_I8" for "first_date_pending".    


`create function ts_to_date(timestamp) returns date as $$
SELECT $1::DATE;
$$
 LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;

create function ts_to_date(TIMESTAMPTZ) returns date as $$
SELECT $1::DATE;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
IMMUTABLE
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;`

Comment: Still no luck, I have now tried converting the date to a string on import but mssql still sees it as a DT_I8